# HTML5 code not working in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

The following simple code works in Firefox (12.0) but does not seem to work in IE 9 even though local storage is supported in IE9. Notice how  alert(localStorage.lastname);   does not show up any results. Was wondering if there is a known issue in using localStorage in IE9 as the documentation does say it is supported.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script> 
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
      alert('local storage')
      localStorage.lastname="Smith";
      alert(localStorage.lastname);  
    }
     else
    {
     alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...")
    }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: My IE9 says `"object"` when I run `typeof(Storage)` in the console. What does your console say when you run that command? I am pretty sure you are trying to run the HTML file locally. Try running it from a web server.

Comment: I do not get it saying object. It does say 'local storage'. Nothing shows upf for alert(localStorage.lastname) thought. It works fine in FireFox 12.0.

Comment: Do you need a `head` element? AFAIK the `title` element is required in order to identify the document when used out of context. Can you try adding `<head><title>Some title...</title></head>` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Are you testing this from a file? Things might start to work if you upload your stuff to a web server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never set/get the items in localstorage directly! Use the appropriate methods for that:

```
localStorage.setItem(key,value)
localStorage.getItem(key)
localStorage.removeItem(key)
```

This fixes your IE problem and you will live happily :-D

(Note, that the values are stores as strings!)

Comment: Hi Christoph, I tried with the following but still doesn't work: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script> 

 if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
 {

    alert('Allows local storage');
   localStorage.setItem("lastname","Smith" );
   alert(localStorage.getItem("lastname"));  
 }
else
  {
  alert("Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...")
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @NatePet besides the fact, that "doesn't work" is not the most precise error-description, it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6G5hm/

Comment: IMO, there's nothing wrong with "localStorage.key = value" usage instead of using setItem().

Comment: @vivek.m well I guess it's the same argument as "I don't need setters and getters, I want to manipulate the data of that encapsulated object all by my self" ... Of course you can do that if you really want to...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine on IE if you host your HTML file on web server.

If you are opening file:// url in IE, then localStorage will be undefined.
Try confirming that with if(typeof(**localStorage**)!=="undefined")
and you will get "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage..."

Answer (score 0):

actually it doesnt even work from a webserver. i am running a web app on websphere application server and i get the same issue on ie9. it works fine on chrome.

you can try the stuff on this page: http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/