# sessionStorage in old versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, session-storage, sessionstorage

I'm trying to use `sessionStorage` to display a modal alert only once per session - and I'm trying to do this in IE versions < 9.

The alert will tell users how terrible their IE version < 9 is, and to please upgrade.

Using `sessionStorage` works fine in IE 11. But in older versions of IE, I can't get it to take effect (`sessionStorage` comes back as 'undefined or null'). I've tested this locally and on a live site. Does `sessionStorage` even work in IE < 9, and if not, what's a good alternative I can use in these older IE versions to only display this alert once per 'session'?

My code looks like:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('browserCheck') !== 'true') {
     // define alert function
     // call alert function
    sessionStorage.setItem('browserCheck','true');
}
```

Comment: Just check to see if `sessionStorage` is defined at all.

Comment: It's not (comes back as 'undefined or null' in the dev tools) - do you know a good alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session storage not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212347/session-storage-not-working-in-ie) but also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916210/html5-code-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: @Rob that question/answer does not address my issue, since I'm testing it on a live site - not just locally.

Comment: Use a storage library that provides cookie fallback like https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, `sessionStorage` *is* valid in IE 7 and 8.
I was just deleting my cache wrong in the browser before switching the dev tools emulator from IE11 to IE 7 or 8. I was able to fix this by unchecking the top box inside of the 'delete history' prompt in IE:
[image]

Earlier, `sessionStorage` *was* coming back as 'undefined or null' in IE 7 and 8 in my dev tools console - but I think this was a because of a separate issue. It isn't undefined - it works.

I believe `localStorage` actually is invalid in IE < 8 though - so if `localStorage` is your problem, this link is helpful: [HTML5 Local Storage fallback solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692245/html5-local-storage-fallback-solutions)